# Count value based on other cell criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have these cells and values :

```
  A          B
1 Apple      5
2 Orange     2
3 Apple      1
4 Mellon     4
5 Mellon     2
```

Column A is the fruit name and column B the fruit count.

I need a formula in google sheet that will count how many fruits we have, for example the result should be :

```
Apple = 6
Orange = 2
Mellon = 6
```

I've tried **countifs** but it only count the number of the "string" criteria as it appears..

Comment: try the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B)

Answer (score 0):

using your example: (having code in B8 and fruitname in A8)

```
{=SUM((A2:A6=A8)*(B2:B6))}
```

array-formula -> ctrl+shift+return

it works in a pretty simple way:

`A2:A6=A8` is true for every cell containung what is in `A8`

```
we got now: TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE
```

then it multiplys it with `B2:B5`

```
TRUE  * 5 = 5
FALSE * 2 = 0
TRUE  * 1 = 1
FALSE * 4 = 0
FALSE * 2 = 0
```

and in the last step, it sums it

```
5 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 = 6
```

done :)

Answer (score 0):

For the Apples use:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"Apple",B:B)
```

For the Melon use:

```
=SUMIF(A:A, "Melon",B:B)
```

and so on.

Comment: :) I'm confident he will figure out, that an 'l' is missing!